# Как прикрутить MouseDown к ModelVisual3D?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как прикрутить MouseDown к ModelVisual3D? Возможно ли это, не трогая ModelUIElement3D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее, несложно.

Во-первых, в 2D-контейнер положите `Background="Transparent"` и подпишитесь на сообщения от мыши. В `MouseDown` вы получите *двухмерные* координаты точки, в которой у вас произошло событие. Вам нужно найти, какому *трёхмерному* объекту это соответствует, вы должны запустить hittest-процедуру (то есть, выяснить, в какой точке *луч*, направленный из этой точки, пересечёт ваши фигуры).

Для этого воспользуйтесь процедурой `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`, которая «приведёт» вас к нужному трёхмерному элементу:

```
void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
{
    Point pos = args.GetPosition(Viewport);
    PointHitTestParameters pp = new PointHitTestParameters(mouseposition);

    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Viewport, null, OnHit, pointparams);
}
```

(имя `Viewport` соответствует, понятно, вашему `Viewport3D`). Если ваш начальный элемент лежит не в 2D-области (например, это `Viewport3D`), а в 3D-области, то вам понадобится использовать трёхмерные параметры, в которых задаётся не только начальная точка, но и *направление*:

```
RayHitTestParameters pp = new RayHitTestParameters(
        new Point3D(mousePoint.X, mousePoint.Y, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
```

Процедура `OnHit` выглядит как-то так:

```
public HitTestResultBehavior OnHit(HitTestResult rawresult)
{
    if (rawresult is RayHitTestResult rayresult) // если это 3D-результат
    {
        // то мы попали в какой-то 3D-объект, и можем с ним работать
        var modelHit = rayresult.ModelHit;
        // обрабатываем

        return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop; // остановить поиск
    }

    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue; // продолжить поиск
}
```

Литература:

- Microsoft Docs, [How to: Hit Test in a Viewport3D](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-hit-test-in-a-viewport3d)
- WPF3D Team Blog, [3D Hit Testing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf3d/2009/05/18/3d-hit-testing/)
- [WPFSamples/HitTest3D/cs/](https://github.com/ariesy/WPFSamples/tree/master/HitTest3D/cs) (тут пример приложения)

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Есть ли способ получать координаты центра 3D-объекта, а не координаты курсора в области этого объекта?

Comment: @ВладиславГлумов: Пожалуйста! По идее есть, смотрите [сюда](https://github.com/ariesy/WPFSamples/blob/master/HitTest3D/cs/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L57) и [сюда](https://github.com/ariesy/WPFSamples/blob/master/HitTest3D/cs/MainWindow.xaml.cs#L152) (выдаёт барицентрические координаты точки).

Comment: Тьфу, вам нужен именно центр? Ну возьмите барицентрические координаты (1/3, 1/3, 1/3).

Comment: Да, именно центр. Разъясните, пожалуйста, Вашу запись (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)?

Comment: @ВладиславГлумов: Ну, у вас есть три вершины: индексы вы получаете через `VertexIndex1`/`2`/`3`, а сами точки лежат в коллекции `Positions`. Вы берёте координаты трёх точек, и складываете их с коэффициентами 1/3, 1/3, 1/3. То есть как бы берёте среднее арифметическое. Это даёт центр тяжести треугольника.

Comment: А разве это дает все три координаты центра самого объекта?

Comment: @ВладиславГлумов: Ну по идее да, а что? Это даёт центр треугольника.

Comment: Я, возможно, неправильно попытался донести свою мысль. Нужно получить координаты 3D-объекта. В моем случае, это шар, который размещается во viewport по 3 координатам, мне нужно, нажимая на этот шар, получить его эти самые три координаты (центр его размещения, от которого исходит радиус и описывает его поверхность). Может быть вы знаете, как это возможно осуществить?

Comment: @ВладиславГлумов: Окей, как у вас представлен шар?